# Upload and show images in Sails JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

With [Sails JS](http://sailsjs.org/#/) I am trying to upload an image and show it in a view.

Questions:

- The image is uploaded in .tmp/uploads, but how can I access it from a view?
- Is there any way to access the image?
- The image name is changed in the directory. Is it possible not to change the name of image?

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1: If you want to use the image in your views you need to change the directory where it is being uploaded by passing a config object to the `upload` method with a `dirname` attribute:

```
req.file('image').upload({
  dirname: '../../assets/images/'
}, function(error, uploadedFiles) {
  // do something after file was uploaded...
});
```

Then, in your view:

```
<img src="/images/fileName.jpg">

// Or, if you are using Jade:
img(src='/images/fileName.jpg')
```

2: I'm not sure what you mean by "access the image", but the image will be saved on your local disk and can be found in `.tmp/uploads/` or the directory that you pass in as `dirname`.

3: To keep the same name as the original file name you need to pass in a `saveAs` attribute to the `upload` method's config object:

```
req.file('image').upload({
  saveAs: function(file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.filename);
  }
}, function(err, uploadedFiles) {
  // do something after file was uploaded...
});
```

You can find more details in the [Skipper documentation](https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper) or [Sails documentation](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/File-Uploads).
Skipper is the module that Sails uses for file uploads.

Comment: Thanks for reply. this worked fine but sometime i have to refresh the page to show the image in view. And about the "access the image" means show the image in view.

Comment: About the need to refresh before seeing the image, I believe that it is a browser caching issue. Maybe you need to append a timestamp or a new random string to your image's href, like `<img href="/images/fileName.jpg?randomString=...">`

Comment: i resolved the refresh issue by: 
`<img src="/images/uploads/file.jpg" onerror="location.reload();">`
this will refresh the page if image is broken.

Comment: By default file upload to ".tmp/uploads/", is there any way to access it directly in browser?

Comment: yuyue007 static files can only be accessed if they are inside the `assets` directory

Answer (score 0):

I have a bit of a different method of handling this since I don't automatically want to expose every file that gets uploaded.

When a file is uploaded, I leave it in a private location, and I create a record in a "Files" model that contains the fd.

I then have a route:

```
config/routes.js

'get  /files/:id' : 'FileControllers.stream',
```

Which points to my controller:

```
api/controllers/FilesController.js

/**
* serve a file
*
* (GET /file/:id)
*/
stream: function (req, res){

    Files.findOne(req.param('id')).exec(function (err, file){
        if (err) return res.negotiate(err);
        if (!file) return res.notFound();

        if (!file.fileDescriptor) {
            return res.notFound();
        }

        res.sendFile(file.fileDescriptor);
    });
}
```

res.sendFile is mentioned in the [Sails documentation](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/response-res) but is fully explained in [express docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile).

In short, res.sendFile:

> Transfers the file at the given path. Sets the Content-Type response
>   HTTP header field based on the filename’s extension.

By running it through a controller, I can still use my policies to dictate access.